# Como percorrer um vetor com a quantidade do segundo vetor?

Tags: java

```
int[] teste1 = {3524, 79, 2573, -4216, -4126, -4169, 1876, 2903, 2702, 1090, -6544, -8600};

int[] teste2 = {3524, 79, 2573, -4216, -4126, -4169};
```

Tenho um vetor com 12 registros e outro com 6, preciso percorrer duas vezes sem repetir.

Exemplo, primeiro processo do **3524** até **4169** depois **1876** até **-8600**.

Estou fazendo isso para comparar o segundo com o primeiro.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < teste1.length/2; i++) {}` ou `for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {}`. Sua dúvida é essa mesmo?

Comment: Desta forma ele vai percorrer 6 registros e parar. Preciso que ele execute duas vezes, primeiro do 0 ao 5 e depois do 6 ao 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
int[] teste1 = {3524, 79, 2573, -4216, -4126, -4169, 1876, 2903, 2702, 1090, -6544, -8600};

    int[] teste2 = {3524, 79, 2573, -4216, -4126, -4169};

    for(int t1=0; t1<teste1.length; t1++){
        int t2 = t1%6;    
        System.out.println("Comparando teste1:"+ teste1[t1] + "com teste2:"+teste2[t2]);

    }
```

O mod dos dois vetores irá retornar exatamente o que você quer! Segue a saída:

```
Comparando teste1:3524 com teste2:3524
Comparando teste1:79 com teste2:79
Comparando teste1:2573 com teste2:2573
Comparando teste1:-4216 com teste2:-4216
Comparando teste1:-4126 com teste2:-4126
Comparando teste1:-4169 com teste2:-4169
Comparando teste1:1876 com teste2:3524
Comparando teste1:2903 com teste2:79
Comparando teste1:2702 com teste2:2573
Comparando teste1:1090 com teste2:-4216
Comparando teste1:-6544 com teste2:-4126
Comparando teste1:-8600 com teste2:-4169
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado!